# ERROR FIREFOX IN SELENIUM 3

Tags: selenium

[i have added gecko driver to system.set property, but still its not launching]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.waitForPortUp(IILjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)V

Comment: Show some code...

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. When I debug my application, I found that it was referring the old Selenium jar. To resolve this, I removed the old jar's and rebuild the project with Selenium 3 jars.

Ensure that you have right libraries added to your project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, you were right. in my case, i removed 2.53 from maven repo , and it works just fine. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got similar issue when I added dependency to phantomdriver to my project pom. Selenium 3.0 got it own dependency to phantomdriver already, which produced dependency conflict and not allows to geckodriver to be started. Solution was to remove additional dependency to phantomdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Hridesh Gupta & user3153853, guys, your answers helped me A LOT! Thanks! 
So I had the same issue, FF was not launching returning an exception:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   ...
    enter code hereCaused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.waitForPortUp(IILjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)
    ...
```

It turned out the same thing - dependencies collision. 
I had:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I added this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Apparently,

```
<version>1.5.3</version>
```

was not compatible with

```
<version>3.0.1</version>
```

so by reducing Ashot's version down to

```
<version>1.5.2</version>
```

I fixed FF issue.